# Is lim sup $s_{n}$ larger than all other tails of $s_{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I was reading a proof and it said that let $q$ = lim sup $s_{n}$.  Then q is the largest possible value any $s_{n}$ in a tail of the sequence of $s_{n}$ can attain.  So, sup $T_{m} \leq q$ where $T_{m} = $ { $s_{n} | n \geq M$}

But as I was thinking about this and I want to say this is false.  Because isn't the lim sup $s_{n}$ = inf sup $s_{n}$? So in fact lim sup $s_{n}$  would be less than any sup $T_{m}$.

Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Indeed, for every $m$, $\sup T_m\geqslant\limsup s_n$ since $\limsup s_n=\inf\limits_m\left(\sup T_m\right)$.